# WMP EventDispatcher: how to know who sent the event?

Tags: c++, windows-media-player, wmp

I am embedding Windows Media Player in a C program. I found the WMP Host example in C++ in the WMP SDK. It contains an even dispatcher. But when I receive an event, how do I know who sent the event and how do I access that class object's variables? For example, I want to set a class member (variable) or call a method.

The CWMPHost object creates the window containing the WMP object and creates the event object. The minimal code is:

```
LRESULT CWMPHost::OnCreate(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
{
    AtlAxWinInit();
    CComPtr<IAxWinHostWindow>           spHost;
    CComPtr<IConnectionPointContainer>  spConnectionContainer;
    CComWMPEventDispatch                *pEventListener = NULL;
    CComPtr<IWMPEvents>                 spEventListener;
    HRESULT                             hr;
    RECT                                rcClient;

    m_dwAdviseCookie = 0;

    // create window
    GetClientRect(&rcClient);
    m_wndView.Create(m_hWnd, rcClient, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, 0);

    // load OCX in window
    hr = m_wndView.QueryHost(&spHost);
    hr = spHost->CreateControl(CComBSTR(_T("{6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6}")), m_wndView, 0);
    hr = m_wndView.QueryControl(&m_spWMPPlayer);

    // start listening to events
    hr = CComWMPEventDispatch::CreateInstance(&pEventListener);
    spEventListener = pEventListener;

    hr = m_spWMPPlayer->QueryInterface(&spConnectionContainer);

    // See if OCX supports the IWMPEvents interface
    hr = spConnectionContainer->FindConnectionPoint(__uuidof(IWMPEvents), &m_spConnectionPoint);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // If not, try the _WMPOCXEvents interface, which will use IDispatch
        hr = spConnectionContainer->FindConnectionPoint(__uuidof(_WMPOCXEvents), &m_spConnectionPoint);
    }
    hr = m_spConnectionPoint->Advise(spEventListener, &m_dwAdviseCookie);

    return 0;
}
```

The full sample code can be found at https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/multimedia/WMP/cpp/WMPHost

Comment: Hmmm...I see a down vote and a close suggestion, but could anybody please help me or tell me what to do?

Comment: You can safely assume that it was WMP that generated the event.  Nobody else will.

Comment: @Hans-Passant, I intend to have more than one player active, so I must know which one.

Comment: The class you use to implement IWMPEvents needs an extra variable that stores a reference to one of the spWMPPlayers.  In general this is not a very sensible thing to do.  WMP is a very heavy object and having more than one play back media at the same time isn't typically very useful.

Comment: @Hans-Pasant, but looking at how the event dispatcher is created in the above code, there is no way to pass it that reference. That's the whole problem. (Please note: I am not a C++ programmer; I am a C programmer, so maybe I lack some required knowledge of C++)

Comment: The code has to be modified, it doesn't get more simple than that.  That this is an obstacle when you don't know C++ is a given, the abstraction level is quite high.  You can't use ATL and smart pointer classes in a C program so none of this code is useful to you.  Writing COM client code in C is outlawed by the Geneva Convention on Programmer's Rights, local exemptions may apply.

Comment: @Hans-Passant, indeed, so I call wrappers from C that then call C++. It works fine, except for things like this. So what would be the way to pass a reference to the parent to the event dispatcher object?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** My improved solution that meets my needs:

First I untangled the include dependencies and applied include guards against circular includes. The `CWMPHost` class *definition* doesn't need to know about the `CWMPEventDispatch` class; however its implementation does, so the `CWMPEventDispatch.h` class definition is included in the `CWMPHost.cpp` file but not in the `CWMPHost.h` file.

This allows to define a member of `CWMPEventDispatch` to be a pointer to the owning `CWMPHost` object:

```
    CWMPHost *pCWMPHost;
```

It is set in the `CWMPHost::Create` method:

```
    hr = CComWMPEventDispatch::CreateInstance(&pEventListener);
    pEventListener->pCWMPHost= this;
```

Now the event dispatcher can access the methods and members of the `CWMPHost` object that created the dispatcher.